# Solution to add className in specific Array element

Tags: reactjs

I created one calendar and I don't find the solution to add one className when the date is equal "today", please see the link demo:

https://compassionate-beaver-fe6c05.netlify.com/

the code is:

https://github.com/fzabra/react-calendar/blob/master/src/Components/Calendar.jsx

The follow condition return the date today:

```
 if (dateDay === today.getDate() && currentYear === today.getFullYear() && currentMonth === today.getMonth()) {
   console.log(dateDay)   
}
```

Observe that the console show the date of today. The square today is a  it element have one id="dateDay", I think something like document.getElementById doesn't work, anybody has any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Where is the style for the current date?

Comment: 'Conditional Rendering'

Comment: Yes, but there's no css style, `dateDay` is a number, add a `today` or something

Comment: I don't create the style yet, I just want to add one className in the current day. I tried push() again between this conditional but it is creating two current day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `.box .green` class from your CSS file, you can `push` the `<Table.Cell>` inside the `if` condition or `else` don't use the `className`, like so:

```
if (dateDay === today.getDate() && currentYear === today.getFullYear() && currentMonth === today.getMonth()) {
  children.push(<Table.Cell key={j} id={dateDay} className="box green">{dateDay}</Table.Cell>)
  } else{
  children.push(<Table.Cell key={j} id={dateDay} className="box">{dateDay}</Table.Cell>)
```

This way the current date will have a green background.
Result
[image]

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/W0a6rp69)

Comment: For me it created 2 current days not for you

Comment: Very nice, now I will understand where I broke my brain haha, thank you